# Appcelerator: How to create Ti.UI.TextArea dynamically adjusting to content but with minimal height

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I want to create a Ti.UI.TextArea object which would dynamically adjust its height to content but would have default height set (if no content). In Appcelerator if you don't specify height then it will automatically adjust its size to content but if there is no text then its size will be similar to textField. This is to small for me.
If you specify height property, then TextArea height won't change even if text will be longer than editable region.

I would like to have something like this:

```
var textArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    minHeight: 30,
});
```

or like this:

```
var textArea = Ti.UI.createTextArea({
    minLines: 3,
});
```

I am looking for solution both for Android and iOS.
Is there any workaround for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the height of the textField dynamically. 
Add onChange event handler and change the height of the textField dynamically according to the number of lines in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 7.5.0.GA you can use `maxLines` on Android to be able to extend the TextArea to when pressing return. For iOS you have to create a work-around since there is no parity at the moment.